# How to access the bean linked in an attribute of UIComponent?

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I need to access the bean object used in a EL expression of an UIComponent.

For example, in this sample code:

**xhtml:**

```
<h:form>
    <f:view>
        <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{baseBean.selected}" onLabel="Instalar" offLabel="Ignorar" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close">
            <f:validator validatorId="baseValidator.items" />
        </p:selectBooleanButton>
        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit"
            actionListener="#{baseBean.process}"
            ajax="false" />
    </f:view>
</h:form>
```

**java:**

```
@FacesValidator("baseValidator.items")
public static class BaseValidator implements Validator
{

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        ValueReference reference = component.getValueExpression("value").getValueReference(context.getELContext());
        Object o1 = reference.getBase();
        Object o2 = reference.getProperty();
        return; //break point here
    }

}
```

When the command button is pressed the `BaseValidator.validate` is executed, I need to get the `baseBean` object used in `<p:selectBooleanButton value="#{baseBean.selected}">`

My code is currently throwing `NullPointerException` because `getValueReference` is returning *null*. How do I get that object inside the validate method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF: Accessing Bean from Validator via field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178783/jsf-accessing-bean-from-validator-via-field)

Answer (score -1):

```
value="#{baseBean.selected}" should be changed as "#{baseBean.value}"
```