# How can you access the @Size annotation of a field in JSF?

Tags: jsf, reflection, annotations

My problem is:

Some of my entity fields need to have an exact length for compatibility reasons. That length is defined via `@Size(min=10, max=10)` or similar on the field. Although the fields are typed as String, they actually contain numbers. Most of the fields have values with leading zeroes, for example: `0000148233`.

Now I don't want to force the user to enter those leading zeroes in the input fields. It should be possible to just enter `148233`.

My first approach was writing a composite component that uses a simple FacesConverter to add leading zeroes on the input, based on an attribute `length`:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="length" required="true"
        type="java.lang.Integer" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <f:converter converterId="leadingZeroesConverter" />
        <f:attribute name="length" value="#{cc.attrs.length}" />
    </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

I read the `length` attribute in the Converter:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    int length = (Integer) component.getAttributes().get("length");
    return Strings.zeroPrefixFillUp(value, length);
}
```

That does work quite well, but I actually don't want to define the length in JSF.

What I would like to do is access the annotation somehow, either in JSF or in the converter. This way I could avoid maintaining that attribute in two places.

In the converter I have the FacesContext and the UIComponent (which is an InputText, obviously). Is there any way to get the field's name (and it's class), so I can access that annotation?

PS: Just to let you know, I stripped all the error handling from the Converter for clarity reasons.

Comment: @BalusC: I don't think this is a duplicate. What is requested here is to be able to use the length in a converter to automatically add leading zeroes...

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178783/jsf-accessing-bean-from-validator-via-field help?

Comment: @Kukeltje: Thank you, that link brought me on the right track. Look at my answer to see a working solution. Any further advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Kukeltje's link kind of brought me on the right track:

I now have two composite attributes, namely `bean` and `field`. Via `cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.field]` I set the inputText's value. In my converter I evaluate the expressions `#{cc.attrs.bean}` and `#{cc.attrs.field}`, which return the bean and the name of the field. Using reflection I can now access the `@Size` annotation.

**The composite component**

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="field" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.bean[cc.attrs.field]}">
        <f:converter converterId="leadingZerosConverter" />
    </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

**The converter**

```
@FacesConverter(value = "leadingZerosConverter")
public class LeadingZerosConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        Object bean = evaluateExpression("#{cc.attrs.bean}", context, Object.class);
        String fieldName = evaluateExpression("#{cc.attrs.field}", context, String.class);
        if (bean == null || fieldName == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bean and field must not be null");
        }
        try {
            Size annotation = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName).getAnnotation(Size.class);
            return Strings.zeroPrefixFillUp(value, annotation.min());
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }   
    }

    private <T> T evaluateExpression(String expression, FacesContext context, Class<T> clazz) {

        ExpressionFactory factory = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        ValueExpression exp = factory.createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), expression, clazz);

        return clazz.cast(exp.getValue(context.getELContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return ((String) value).replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do add exceptionhandling

Comment: Done. Also, I figured out `UIComponent.getCurrentCompositeComponent(context).getAttributes().get("bean");` will return the composite attribute `cc.attrs.bean` as well. So there's no need to mess around with Expression Language in `evaluateExpression()`.